# How to set a proxy for MySQL in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, proxy

***This question may seems duplicate, but it’s really not.*** I have read many of other questions and answers from stackoverflow and also other website but non would match to my requirement.

In most of proxy questions, the matter is just to connect from X => Z going through Y as proxy.

My requirement is to change the query coming from X in proxy(Y) and send it to Z and then getting the result back to the X.

***Here is a little more explanation:***

I want to make a daemon service which act as proxy (localhost:3310) for MySQL database(localhost:3306) no clients know the address of database, they just know the ip address of proxy thinking it’s the database. So they try connection to it by hostname(localhost:3310) and valid MySQL username and password.

Now when a query comes to the port 3310, the proxy which is to be in java just changes the query say for example (`select name from employee;` => `select substr(name,1,3) from employee;`) and send the changed query to the MySQL Server and get the reply back to the user application (Desktop/Web).

(How) Is it possible to do so in Java?

Comment: I highly suspect this to be an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and solving the problem you're having that way will force you to reimplement the MySQL wire protocol server side in Java, and understand (parse) a sizeable portion of the SQL language to know what to modify, and how. Doable, but a tremendous waste of time for what I suspect can be solved with a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views.html).

Comment: The logic of my program is more complex to be done by view ( it's much more than simple query I have given as example). also I want the proxy so no one have my Database IP.

Comment: In that case see the first part of my comment. There used to be github.com/mysql/mysql-proxy but that project was apparently abandoned. It should however be possible to use it for your goal, and at least you can skip the phase of having to reimplement the wire protocol.

Comment: Hi Majid NK do you any solution for this ....